# neo4j Cypher create or updating

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using Neo 2.0 through REST API /cypher I'm trying to build a rooted tree like structure.

I currently have an indexed start node, I want to attach a unique path of nodes which may already exist. How can I get cypher to create and set or just update if its already in the database but missing certain properties.

Answer (score 1):

Cypher's `MERGE` command does this, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-merge.html.

Comment: I haven't been able to get MERGE to work through the REST API only the neo4j console. Additionally it also doesn't mention anything about the relationships, only nodes.

Comment: OK by updating to M3 merge now seems to do something through REST however, The error response is "MERGE only supports single node patterns\" but I want to update it with a path and fill in missing nodes or potentially update the properties of the nodes if they already exsist

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue currently. I'm looking into `CREATE UNIQUE` might be what you are after.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-create-unique.html

---

edited: actually I think `CREATE UNIQUE` might be deprecated.